# Prolog: single item vs single item list

Tags: prolog

While troubleshooting a larger assignment for school, I found a mistake I had made, where I was treating a single item list (a stack with one item) as if it were a single item.  I solved my issue, however in further testing I noticed something weird:

```
48 ?- 1 is [1].
true.

49 ?- -1 is [-1].
ERROR: is/2: Type error: `character' expected, found `-1'

50 ?- 0.66 is [0.66].
ERROR: is/2: Type error: `character' expected, found `0.66'
```

Similar behavior happens using =:=/2 instead of is/2.  So for whatever reason, a single item list is considered the same as a single item, but only for non-negative integers.

Curiosity more than anything else... anybody know why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org) (and perhaps others), this is related to a [backward compatibility implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%284,%274.25.2.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/arith.html%27%29%29) of expressions for evaluation by `is/2` and `=:=/2`:

```
.(+Int,[])

A list of one element evaluates to the element. This implies "a" evaluates to 
the character code of the letter `a' (97). This option is available for 
compatibility only. It will not work if `style_check(+string)' is active as "a"
will then be transformed into a string object. The recommended way to specify the
character code of the letter `a' is 0'a.
```

As character codes are non-negative integers, this may explain why the behaviour you're seeing only works for such numbers and not floating point and negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to be the answer, as "97 is [a]." is true.  However, maybe I'm an idiot, but I can't really understand exactly what is being described on that manual page.  The predicates listed (min, max, abs, etc) don't seem to to exist for me, and I don't get why all the arguments have + signs in front.  And I don't get why the predicate pertaining to this Q is just a dot with two arguments, I'm not using anything like that.

Comment: That page is about SWI-Prolog; perhaps your implementation doesn't support min, max, etc.? Some arguments are preceded by `+` as this indicates mode, i.e., `+` means bound (and not variable). Lastly, list syntax `[a,b]` is shorthand for the `./2` list constructor predicate (so is actually `.(a,.(b,[]))`). In your case, a single-integer list like `[1]` is shorthand for `.(1,[])`.

Comment: Ok, great explanations... I think I got it now.  Thanks again.